# I'm unable to incorporate .ttf or .otf font files into my html page

Tags: font-face

here's my HTML file with h1, p and span tags :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Fonts</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is Archi - <span>Welcome!</span></h1>
<p class="myFontStyling">dfrzgtiujhgfdsfghyjgku</p>
</body>
</html>
```

here's my CSS file that incorporates .ttf file to style the font of an element or contents in a tag :-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myFirstFont';
  src: 
        url('fonts/CoHeadlineCorpFont/Co-Headline-Corp-Light.ttf');
        format('truetype');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.myFontStyling {
  font-family: 'myFirstFont';
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'myFirstFont', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

here's my directory structure :-

```
fontsByArchi
 -fonts
  -CoHeadlineCorpFont
   -Co-Headline-Corp-Light.ttf
 -index.html
 -style.css
```

I am unable to get the font effect on my texts, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forgot to refer external css file in html page. After adding      `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` tag inside `<head>` I was above see it getting applied.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Custom Fonts</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is Archi - <span>Welcome!</span></h1>
<p class="myFontStyling">dfrzgtiujhgfdsfghyjgku</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh yes, that worked - it was so silly of me to have overlooked such basic aspect. Thanks by the way.

Comment: :) there's one more aspect that I'm exploring now - carousel : have u worked on this?

Comment: You mean carousel in JS ? yes

Comment: could u plz have a look at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413127/vertical-bootstrap-carousel-on-mouse-scroll-to-occur-after-scrolling-for-a-whi